# MSSQL query returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

the query:

```
SELECT sv_inquiry.inquiry_id, sv_inquiry.owner_rep, sv_inquiry.status
      ,sv_inquiry.owner_rep, sv_inquiry.closed_dt 
FROM sv_inquiry 
WHERE sv_inquiry.typ = 'incident' 
     AND sv_inquiry.status = 'resolved' 
     AND sv_inquiry.owner_grp = 'service center NL & INT' 
     AND sv_inquiry.closed_dt LIKE '%17-6-2013%' 
ORDER BY sv_inquiry.inquiry_id DESC
```

the problem:

This query returns an empty resultset unless I leave out "`AND sv_inquiry.closed_dt LIKE '%17-6-2013%'`", but if I leave that out I get all the results from the last couple of years and I only need to have the results from a specific date.

`sv_inquiry.closed_dt is a field of the DATETIME type`.

I should probably implement the use of CAST or CONVERT, although I don't know how to adjust the query to include that and only show results of a specific date.

(the query is used on PHP site with `SQLSRV_QUERY` statement)

Can anyone adjust the query for me so I can search a specific date with the `sv_inquiry.closed_dt` field?

Answer (score 3):

Just cast it to date and compare it. It is available in sql server 2008 and newer.

```
AND CAST(sv_inquiry.closed_dt AS DATE) = '2013-06-17'
```

Comment: What about indexes? Won't CAST force the optimizer to do a table scan?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually it won't. Casting from datetime to date, should be able to make optimizer utilize datetime index

Comment: +1 if it does, I'll have to check the query execution plan first

Comment: Just checked the execution plan, and SQL Server does use the index despite the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
AND sv_inquiry.closed_dt LIKE '%17-6-2013%'
```

with

```
AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, sv_inquiry.closed_dt)) = '2013-06-17'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e848/7)

To overcome the problem that this won't use indexes I suggest you split the `datetime` column in to seperate columns: `date` and `time` like `sv_inquiry.closed_date` and `sv_inquiry.closed_time`.

Comment: This will invalidate any indexes on closed_dt

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So will using `%..%`

Comment: `%..%` is worse, it will force a conversion to string that can succeed only by accident (if the literal and column/table/database use the same collation)

Comment: So we agree Juergen's solution is better.

Comment: No, '2013-6-17' is not the multilingual format. '20130617' is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It's in the docs, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#UsingDateandTimeFormats . Check the Multilanguage column. Used to fall for this in the past as well. In fact, I started my own answer using the separated format, before I remembered this issue :$

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a datetime value with a string literal. To do that, SQL Server must either convert the datetime value to a string using the column's collation, or convert the string to a datetime, if it can determine its format. '17-6-2013' is not a recognizable format so SQL Server converts the `dt_closed` value to string before comparing.

'2013-6-17' is not a safe option either. It is [one of the formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#UsingDateandTimeFormats) that are not affected by the DATEFORMAT property, but it is still affected by the collation.

The only safe format is '20130617', the unseparated ISO 8601 format.

You can bypass the entire issue of conversion by using a parameterized SQL statement and pass the filter value as a date parameter.

Another issue is that applying any sort of function to the column `dt_closed` will cause the query optimizer to ignore any indexes defined on dt_closed and force a table scan.

A better solution is to convert the equality operation to a range query using `BETWEEN` eg.

```
AND sv_inquiry.closed_time between '20130617' AND '20130618'
```

This will avoid conversions to string and utilize any underlying indexes

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
AND sv_inquiry.closed_dt LIKE '%17-6-2013%'
```

with

```
AND convert(varchar(10),sv_inquiry.closed_dt, 121) = '2013-06-17'
```

That will cast your datetime to a varchar using the `121`format. Due to the length limitation to 10 chars, it will only return the datepart.

Alternativly, you can use

```
AND convert(varchar(100),sv_inquiry.closed_dt, 121) like '2013-06-17%'
```

if you sometimes dynamically need to check the hours and so on as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT sv_inquiry.inquiry_id, sv_inquiry.owner_rep, sv_inquiry.status
  ,sv_inquiry.owner_rep, sv_inquiry.closed_dt 
 FROM sv_inquiry 
  WHERE sv_inquiry.typ = 'incident' 
 AND sv_inquiry.status = 'resolved' 
 AND sv_inquiry.owner_grp = 'service center NL & INT' 
 AND sv_inquiry.closed_dt ='2013-6-17'
 order BY sv_inquiry.inquiry_id DESC
```